# ZFS groupused value not current

Tags: solaris, disk-usage, zfs, quota

On my Solaris 11 box I have a zfs pool (z) that uses 100G group quotas on each user in /org/users folder. One user had reached their quota and cleaned up their data. The df output, that had previously displayed 100G, now shows their directory is now under 1G. However, zfs groupquota still thinks they are at 100G.

```
-bash-4.1$ sudo /usr/sbin/zfs get groupquota@12345 z/org/users
NAME       PROPERTY           VALUE  SOURCE
z/org/users  groupquota@123451  none   local
-bash-4.1$ sudo /usr/sbin/zfs get groupused@12345 z/org/users
NAME       PROPERTY          VALUE  SOURCE
z/org/users  groupused@12345  100G   local
```

I've tried refreshing their quota to fix but it doesn't seem to change. The delete_queue appears to have 3 items, so I wouldn't think that would be causing this much discrepancy. I also looked for open files (deleted) and didn't turn up anything promising:

```
sudo find /proc/*/fd -type f -links 0
```

What am I missing? Anyone know any tricks for this?

Comment: have you check for the existence of snapshots?

Comment: Yeah, no snapshots in play here @BitsOfNix

Comment: Is there anything in `zfs list -r -t all z`?  What does `zfs get -r all z | grep used` show?

Answer (score 0):

Had some time to look into this. Perhaps could you share your Solaris version?
I have tried this on a Solaris 11.3 system:

```
# pkg list entire
NAME (PUBLISHER)                                  VERSION                    IFO
entire                                            0.5.11-0.175.3.1.0.5.0     i--

# zfs set groupquota@staff=2G rpool/export/home/testquota
# su - testquota
$ mkfile 3G 3gFile
3gFile: initialized 2179989504 of 3221225472 bytes: Disc quota exceeded

# zfs get groupused@staff rpool/export/home/testquota
NAME                         PROPERTY         VALUE  SOURCE
rpool/export/home/testquota  groupused@staff  2.03G  local

$ rm -rf 3gFile

$ zfs get groupused@staff rpool/export/home/testquota
NAME                         PROPERTY         VALUE  SOURCE
rpool/export/home/testquota  groupused@staff  7K     local
```

Comment: Solaris 11.3 sorry for not including the minor in the original Question. That said, issue was resolved by migrating the customer to another zfs pool. :(